# Comma operator on defining variables

Tags: javascript, comma-operator

I'm interesting in logic which used to split string into expressions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator says

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

The question is:

If I have string of code

```
 var x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
```

where I can read why js recognize it as

```
var (x = 1), (y = 2), (z = 3);
```

and not as

```
var x = (1, y = 2, z = 3); // => x should be 3
```

Comment: It's not a comma operator inside a `var` declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place - you should be looking at the `var` definition:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

basically, syntax of `var` is following:
`var varname1 [= value1] [, varname2 [= value2] ... [, varnameN [= valueN]]]];`